# How to replace column values by matching values in a dictionary of a different length in Python?

Tags: python, scala, pandas, dictionary, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that kind of looks like this

```
ID   Color
A    red
B    green
C    red
D    yellow
```

I've enumerated the colors into numbers by creating a dictionary:

```
color_list = ['red', 'green', 'yellow']
colors = dict(enumerate(color_list))
```

Now how do I replace the column values with, essentially, color IDs, so that the data frame would look like the following:

```
ID  Color
A    1
B    2
C    1
D    3
```

**EDIT**: As a follow up questions, if I had the same data in a Spark RDD, how would I tackle it in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [pd.factorize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['Color'] = pd.factorize(df['Color'])[0]
```

Demo:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
  ID   Color
0  A     red
1  B   green
2  C     red
3  D  yellow

In [20]: df['Color'] = pd.factorize(df['Color'])[0]

In [21]: df
Out[21]:
  ID  Color
0  A      0
1  B      1
2  C      0
3  D      2
```

Alternatively we can convert `Code` column to categorical dtype:

```
In [24]: df['Color'] = df['Color'].astype('category')

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
  ID   Color
0  A     red
1  B   green
2  C     red
3  D  yellow

In [26]: df.dtypes
Out[26]:
ID         object
Color    category   # <----------
dtype: object
```

we can use categorical codes (numbers):

```
In [27]: df.Color.cat.codes
Out[27]:
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    2
dtype: int8
```